# Twilio difference between SmsStatusCallback and StatusCallback

Tags: php, twilio

The page [here](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/applications) at twilio explains about SmsStatusCallback and StatusCallback.
Both of those take URL as input where they post the response.

It says the SmsStatusCallback should give me status, but it does not. Where is StatusCallback is POST'ing the data very well.

So what is difference between them and why SmsStatusCallback is not posting any data, it do delivers the data.

```
$sms = $client->account->sms_messages->create($twilioNumber, $number, "Test message", array("SmsStatusCallback" => $posturl) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out the thing, sharing here, so might be useful for others too.

The SmsStatusCallback is made for application built from twilio ( they give you option on the dashboard to create application). So using the SmsStatusCallback post the data to the twilio application and not the post url.

Where as the StatusCallback post the data to the post url directly.

In short, SmsStatusCallback is for twilio application and StatusCallback is for posting data to any particular URL specified.